# SolrCloud server restart hangs

Tags: solrcloud

I am using SolrCloud with 2 shards (no replicas), both running in the same machine. I use a separate Zookeeper instance. The problem I am facing is that if I reboot the server, SolrCloud fails to start up .

Log in the first shard:
    May 23, 2013 3:10:53 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory close
    INFO: Releasing directory:/opt/solr-4.1.0/example/solr/my-collection/data
    May 23, 2013 3:10:53 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory close
    INFO: Releasing directory:/opt/solr-4.1.0/example/solr/my-collection/data/index
    May 23, 2013 3:11:01 PM org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader$3 process
    INFO: Updating live nodes... (2)

Log in the second shard:
    May 23, 2013 3:11:09 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory close
    INFO: Releasing directory:/opt/solr-4.1.0/example2/solr/my-collection/data
    May 23, 2013 3:11:09 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory close
    INFO: Releasing directory:/opt/solr-4.1.0/example2/solr/my-collection/data/index

To start the service, I have to delete the entire data folder in SolrCloud shards and start again. Deleting just the tlog folder also does not help. Is there a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: take a look into this link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically

Comment: I was able to start solr at boot up - my problem is that the server does not start and just hangs and I guess this something specific to SolrCloud as I have not faced this issue in non-cloud solr installations

Answer (score 0):

There would be a zoo_data folder created in your solr home directory.Delete that folder and then do a restart.It might help in your case.