# Start SOLR on Apache Start

Tags: solr, startup, boot

I run my websites on a dedicated server. I have full control.

I placed a start.sh file like

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/solr-4.3.0/example
/usr/bin/java -jar start.jar
```

in /root

then I gave it world execution permission with

```
chmod og+x start.sh
```

then I placed

```
$HOME/start.sh
```

into /etc/rc.local

After restarting apache, SOLR home page at http:domain.com:8983/solr is not accessible

Comment: See previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically

Comment: That is exactly the steps I have listed here and since it didn't work, I decided to ASK why it doesn't, in a separate question.