# where is daemon command in rhel?

Tags: linux, daemon, rhel

I write a service script following [service script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically)
but I found there no daemon command, and I can't google how to install it

Answer (score 5):

From `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles`:

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

   ...

Functions in /etc/init.d/functions
=======================================

daemon  [ --check <name> ] [ --user <username>] 
        [+/-nicelevel] program [arguments] [&]
 ...
```

Comment: I add this line :. /etc/init.d/functions . to script,but it can't work .the tip is: daemon parameters is wrong. where I did miss