# run solr like daemon

Tags: bash, solr, init.d

I try to make solr to run as a startup script in /etc/init.d/solr.
This is script that I copypasted from [How to start Solr automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prerequisites:
# 1. Solr needs to be installed at /usr/local/solr/example
# 2. daemon needs to be installed
# 3. Script needs to be executed by root

# This script will launch Solr in a mode that will automatically respawn if it
# crashes. Output will be sent to /var/log/solr/solr.log. A PID file will be
# created in the standard location.

# Comments to support chkconfig on Red Hat Linux
# chkconfig: 2345 64 36
# Description: A very fast and reliable search engine.
# processname solr

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start () {
    echo -n "Starting solr..."

    # start daemon
    daemon --chdir='/usr/local/solr/example' --command "java -jar start.jar" --respawn --output=/var/log/solr/solr.log --name=solr --verbose

    RETVAL=$?
    if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
    then
        echo "done."
    else
        echo "failed. See error code for more information."
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}

stop () {
    # stop daemon
    echo -n "Stopping solr..."

    daemon --stop --name=solr  --verbose
    RETVAL=$?

    if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
    then
        echo "done."
    else
        echo "failed. See error code for more information."
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}


restart () {
    daemon --restart --name=solr  --verbose
}


status () {
    # report on the status of the daemon
    daemon --running --verbose --name=solr
    return $?
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    status)
        status
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: solr {start|status|stop|restart}"
        exit 3
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

I did everything as described in above link. But get an error

```
service solr start
Starting solr.../etc/init.d/solr: Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}
failed. See error code for more information.
```

reading https://blog.hazrulnizam.com/create-init-script-centos-6/ I don't understand why daemon was written incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because the `daemon` function (from `/etc/init.d/functions`) has changed since 2010 (when the script was posted) and no longer accepts the same arguments. You will need to rewrite the `daemon` line to accept the currently supported arguments.

I had a look at the `daemon` function on a CentOS 6 box, and it looks like you might be able to replace this line:

```
daemon --chdir='/usr/local/solr/example' --command "java -jar start.jar" --respawn --output=/var/log/solr/solr.log --name=solr --verbose
```

with just this:

```
daemon "java -jar /usr/local/solr/example/start.jar"
```

(assuming that `solr` is installed in `/usr/local/solr/example`).