# How to set up Solr on server?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, java 1.6 and Solr 4.7.0. I'm new to Solr and Search Engines in general but trying to learn.
I have installed Solr on my VPS Ubuntu server doing simply, in my root folder :

```
curl -LO https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.7.0/solr-4.7.0.tgz
tar xvzf solr-4.7.0.tgz
cd solr-4.7.0
cd example
java -jar start.jar
```

and now Solr is successfully reachable at http://my_server_ip:8983/solr and also for all my websites on this server for example : http://mywebsite1:8983/solr etc..

So my questions are :

1. Is this normal in production that Solr is available so easily ? Do I have to restrain its accessibility , with a Virtual Host or anything like that ?
2. How to always run the Solr server so that when I quit my VPS console, the Solr server keeps on working ? 
   **UPDATE** For this question, I have found a working answer here : [How to start Solr automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically) (the second one with /etc/init.d using a daemon).

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: There is a rather good [security topic in solr's wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Solr doesn't have any built-in security. You'll have to use your firewall or custom configuration of your application container (i.e. Jetty) for any extra security.

The easiest way is to bind jetty to localhost (so that it's not available through the internet) or install Solr on a server that's not reachable from the public internet.