# How to start Apache Solr automatically?

Tags: java, php, apache, solr

How can I run Apache Solr jar file (located on 'Solr/example/') automatically in web server?

I need to run 'java -jar start.jar' command automatically

In localhost, I am able to run this jar file using command Prompt(using  "java -jar start.jar") but i couldn't run this file on web server. please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically

Comment: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-solr-startup-script/

Comment: voting to close as duplicate.