# How to run multiple SOLR instances automatically on startup?

Tags: solr

I have configured my SOLR to start automatically on startup by following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically) instructions. This works fine for single instance of SOLR. However, I want to start multiple instances on startup and I've made the following changes in my rc.local file:

```
/home/ubuntu/solr1_start.sh && /home/ubuntu/solr2_start.sh && /home/ubuntu/solr3_start.sh
```

where each start.sh script has the command to run the corresponding SOLR instance on different ports.

The problem is that when I reboot my server, it only starts the first instance and doesn't start solr2 and solr3 instances. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What do the solr logs for the servers that didn't come up say? Also have you tried passing every script execution command on a separate line without the `&&`?

Comment: @BinoyDalal  Yes, I tried putting each script on a separate line. That didn't work too. Where can I find the solr logs?

Comment: Solr_home/server/log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the commands a little bit and it worked.

```
cd /home/ubuntu/solr1/example
nohup /usr/bin/java -jar start.jar > output.log 2>&1 &

cd /home/ubuntu/solr2/example
nohup /usr/bin/java -Djetty.port=8984 -jar start.jar > output2.log 2>&1 &
```