# How to make Solr start automatically on reboot in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: solr, redhat, rhel, reboot

How can I make Solr start automatically on reboot in Red Hat Linux?

How to make Solr start automatically is a question that has been asked and received a variety of answers at [How to start Solr automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically)

However, I'm finding none of the 8 different approaches suggested work on Red Hat.  Does someone on Red Hat have an approach that works?

To start solr manually, I change into the solr install directory and run...
bin/solr start

I'm using RHEL 7.

Comment: The Service Installation Script should work on RHEL, but I'm not sure about the supported versions: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/taking-solr-to-production.html#service-installation-script

Comment: @MatsLindh  I've had no trouble installing Solr.  I just can't figure out how to get it to restart automatically when the machine reboots.

Comment: @MatsLindh -- Thanks!  After installing Solr as a service, like you suggested, I'm now able to get it to restart automatically on reboot.  I just needed to add the chkconfig comments to /etc/init.d/solr as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561621/861826 -- change 'myscript' to solr -- and I needed to do 'chkconfig --add solr'.  I did not need any of the scripts mentioned in the StackOverflow question/answers I've linked to.